# Linearly Independent Vectors of a Set

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, optimization, linear-programming

Let $(^1,...,^)⊂^$, where $k≥n$.

Does $[(^1,...,^)]=^$? (i.e. does the set $(^1,...,^)$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors?)

I need to show how I can solve this decision problem by solving at most  linear programming problems.

Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: Consider $\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Btw it is better to use $\{$ and $\}$ for sets, rather than $($ and $)$.

Comment: As for how you can check., a common technique is to lay the vectors out as rows or columns in a matrix and row reduce, thus being able to check the rank of the matrix and thus the dimension of the span of the vectors.

Comment: In regards to "*I can solve this decision problem by solving at most $n$ linear programming problems*" I don't understand quite what you mean.  What constitutes a single linear programming problem in this context?

Comment: @JMoravitz I think what the question means it to go through values of $n=1,...,$ and see if any value of $n$ violates the statement. It seems that the statement doesn't hold for $n=2$ but what about for $n=1$ ?

Comment: @halrankard2 It is an interesting point that, if you insist this is a *set* rather than a *tuple*, then the statement becomes false in finite fields. For example, if $|F|=k$, then the span of $k^n$ different vectors must be the whole $F^n$ because ... well ... that is how many vectors there are altogether, and by insisting it is a set you insist that they are all different.

Comment: We are told we can make use of this result to answer the question:

Let ${q^1 , . . . , q^n} ⊂ R^n$ be a basis for $R^n$. Then $span(p^1 , . . . , p^k)= R^n$ if and only if $q^j ∈ span (p^1 , . . . , p^k)$ for each $j = 1, . . . ,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. $\{(1,0),(2,0)\}\subset\Bbb R^2$, but $\text{span}\big((1,0),(2,0)\big)=\text{span}\big((1,0)\big)\neq\Bbb R^2$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does the statement hold for the $R^1$ space?

Comment: @codemachine98 uuuh.... $\Bbb R^1$ will be spanned by any nonzero vector... so so long as your $k$ vectors are not all identically the zero vector you'll span $\Bbb R^1$ easily.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^1$ you can take the zero vector as a counterexample. In $\Bbb R^n$ with $n\ge 2$ you can take any nonzero vector $v$ and consider $kv$ with $k\in\Bbb R$. Take as many vectors of this type as you want and you'll get a counterexample.